# Sort array of object by key name 'val' , using lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash

I have below array of objects , and i want to sort it .

```
     var points = [
{
    val: '0.10',
    text: '$0.10'
},
{
    val: '0.50',
    text: '$0.50'
},
{
    val: '1',
    text: '$1'
},
{
    val: '2',
    text: '$2'
},
{
    val: '3',
    text: '$3'
},
{
    val: '10',
    text: '$10'
},
{
    val: '20',
    text: '$20'
},
{
    val: '25',
    text: '$25'
},
{
    val: '50',
    text: '$50'
},
{
    val: '75',
    text: '$75'
},
{
    val: '100',
    text: '$100'
},
{
    val: '150',
    text: '$150'
},
{
    val: '200',
    text: '$200'
},
{
    val: '250',
    text: '$250'
},
{
    val: '300',
    text: '$300'
},
{
    val: '400',
    text: '$400'
},
{
    val: '1000',
    text: '$1,000'
},
{
    val: 'Other',
    text: 'Other'
}
```

]

I have tried below sorting function  -

```
        function myFunction() {
          points.sort(function(a, b){return a.val - b.val});
          console.log(points)
        }
```

But this is returning me wrong output.
I have also tried using orderby and sortby but still getting wrong output.

> _.orderBy(points,['val'],['asc'])
>
> _.sortBy(points, 'val')

By using both options i am getting wrong sorted values.

Comment: Sorting for `numbers` and `strings` are NOT equal. You have `strings` in the field `val`.

Comment: I just wanted to do the same @Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Use this sort method -

```
points.sort(function(a,b){
 return parseInt(a.val)  - parseInt(b.val);
})
```

Comment: By mistake i have written ( a-b) . still getting wrong values

Comment: use Number() instead of parseInt() since parseInt() will lost precision